# Writing generic javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I'am using a generic interface to define my CRUD methods like this :

```
/**
 * Add to data base
 * @param <T> 
 * @return
 */
public T persist(T t);

public T update(T t);

public List<T> findAll();

public T findById(long id);

public void delete(long id);
```

I would like to write some generic `javadoc` but I have trouble to make them work. I want them to change according to the T value

Comment: I think your real problem is what you want to use your Javadoc for. Telling that the param `t` is a `T` isn’t very helpful since we can already read this from the code. Rather write `@param t The object to persist` or similar.

Comment: Type binding happening at runtime and not compile time. At the time of generating java doc its just indicator of Type so its not possible. But it will display proper Type of class in intelligence IDEs like IntelJIdea, Eclipse.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'am asking if there is a way some when displaying the javadoc it will change according to `T` value

Comment: Then let me ask the other way around: Why do you want this? I’m thinking that if you can show us a compelling case where this is needed, we can better suggest how to solve your real problem. What I know is that (as @PankajPatel said) an IDE will already show you the concrete type, and that static generated Javadoc can’t.